# How to preserve new lines while printing to a text file in shell?

Tags: shell, awk

I have to print out some values in a txt file.
they are of the following format

```
input="Sno;Name;Field1;Field2"
```

However the output must be:

```
Sno-Name
FIELDS ALLOCATED:
Field1
Field2
```

I do it like so:

```
 echo $input | $(awk -F';' '{print $1"-"$2}') >>$txtfile
 echo "FIELDS ALLOCATED:">>$txtfile
 echo "$input" | cut -d';' -f 3,4 >>$txtfile
```

This is easy. However, the problem is that Field1 or Field2 can contain new lines. Whenever this happens, the cut or awk doesn't read the field number 4 and treats it as a new line. Do help how can I print the two fields (with new lines preserved) from the given input format.

Comment: Is the number of fields fixed?  Your comment to @tripleee implies not.  The reason I ask is that otherwise there does not appear to be a field delimiter.  In your first example you show semi-colons between fields, but in the second you show newlines.  If a newline is a field delimiter, and you don't know how many fields, then how can you tell when one field ends and the next starts?

Comment: @cdarke the input had ";" as the delimiter and I have to now convert it into  an output delimited with new lines while also preserving the original newlines. As you can see the Field1,Field2 are below each other, so it doesn't matter how many fields. Example, Field1: xxx \n yyy Field2: zzzz \n aaaa
it should print xxx \n yyy \n zzzz \n aaaa

Comment: Ah, OK, so the input field delimiter is a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input=$'Sno;Name;Field1\nFoo;Field2'

awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "\n\n+" ; FS = ";" } { print $1"-"$2; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) {print $i}}' <<<"$input"
```

Since it does not know how many field I can give, i added a for loop until NF and changed the RS to a blank line instead of newline.

Answer (score 3):

If the input is well-formed, you can collect input lines until you have four fields.

```
awk -F ';' 'r { $0 = r ORS $0 }
    NR<4 { next }
    {   print $1 "-" $2
        print "FIELDS ALLOCATED:"
        print $3; print $4
        print ""; r="" }' file
```

Comment: what does `$0 = r` imply? And what if the input can have several fields FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3 and we can't be sure how many?

Comment: The assignment `$0 = r ORS $0` glues the current line to the end of `r` with a newline in front, and recalculates the field count; so we are collecting lines in `r` until it contains four fields.

Comment: If you don't know how many fields there ase and some of them could contain newlines, there is no way to parse your data, because the format is ambiguous. Perhaps there is e.g. a pattern which allows us to identify the first of the last field, but with the information you have provided, your problem cannot be solved for variable field lengths.

Comment: If you somehow know when opening the file how many fields there are, you can use `awk -v f=4 '... NF<f { next } ...}`

Comment: ... Though if you know your input is exactly one record, it's easy again. I wrote this answer on the assumption that you have a semicolon-separated input file which could contain more than one record, but if it's always exactly one, that should be plausible.

Answer (score 2):

Single `gnu-awk` can do the job with `FPAT` and empty `RS`:

```
input=$'Sno;Name;Field1\nFoo;Field2'

awk -v RS= -v FPAT='[^;]+' '{
    printf "%s-%s\nFIELDS ALLOCATED:\n%s\n%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' <<< "$input"

Sno-Name
FIELDS ALLOCATED:
Field1
Foo
Field2
```

Comment: This does not cope with embedded newlines in the field values, because Awk by default reads a line at a time.

Comment: @anubhava That will still break if two newlines are together.

Comment: IMO any CSV has to have defined record separator. Same `\n` cannot be record separator and be present in unquoted cell value.

Comment: I tried the same command, copy paste, it did not work, i get
`Sno;Name;Field1-Foo;Field2` and next line: `FIELDS ALOOCATED`

Comment: I just stepped out. Will provide you a working demo once I get back in 40 minutes.

Comment: FPAT is only available in gnu-awk 4.0+, likely op does not have it.

Comment: [Check this working demo](http://ideone.com/aRVWKL) However you should awk ver 4 and above to be able to use `FPAT`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the input record separator in `awk` - `RS`.  < and > added around each field for clarity.

EDIT:  removed extra trailing newline by adding ';' at the end of the here-doc data, plus another condition.

```
input="Sno;Name;Fie
ld1;Fi
eld2"

awk 'BEGIN{RS=";"} NR==1{f1=$0}; 
     NR==2{print f1 "-" $0; print "FIELDS ALLOCATED:"}
     $0=="\n"{next}
     NR>2{print "<" $0 ">"}' <<< "$input;"
```

Gives:

```
Sno-Name
FIELDS ALLOCATED:
<Fie
ld1>
<Fi
eld2>
```

Comment: Why does field2 have an extra newline at the end?

Comment: Not sure if its the here-doc or `awk`, good point though (EDIT).

Comment: It isn't the here-string. Must be awk.

Comment: I got the solution with your help, thanks, however i did it a little differently